# Problem with pkg behind a chunking proxy

Tags: freebsd, proxy, http

I have a freshly installed FreeBSD 10.1 at work in a VM. As it is behind a corporate proxy, I had to set `HTTP_PROXY` in environment and it began to run fine.

But no way to get `pkg` to work correctly. I installed it from ports, still same issue :

```
root@FriBi:~ # pkg update -f
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
pkg: repository meta /var/db/pkg/FreeBSD.meta has wrong version or wrong format
Fetching meta.txz:   0%
pkg: No signature found
pkg: repository FreeBSD has no meta file, using default settings
Fetching packagesite.txz:   0%
pkg: No signature found
pkg: Unable to update repository FreeBSD
root@FriBi:~ #
```

I was finally able to by-pass the proxy ... and it immediately runned fine ... So I tried to analyze the HTTP dialog. The corporate proxy always sends its responses with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` which I suspected to be the cause.  I could even confirm it by using a minimal Python proxy that :

- get the response from the corporate proxy with `readall()` buffering the whole file
- send it back with a `ContentLength` header to its client (here `pkg`)

and then again it worked (I could do `pkg install xorg` ...)

My questions :

- is `pkg` really hostile to chunking proxy or could it be a local problem of configuration ?
- if it was, should it not be documented somewhere (could not find anything about that)
- is there any simple and nice trick (an *official* proxy for example) to tranform a chunked HTTP response into a not chunked one ?

#### EDIT

The proposed patch has been integrated in 1.5 version and this problem is now solved by that version of pkgng.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last developpements on this issue :

- filed as a bug report to FreeBSD [Bug198772](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198772)
- submitted in mailling list [freebsd-pkg](https://docs.freebsd.org/mail/current/freebsd-pkg.html) and got confirmation that pkg 1.4 cannot process chunked responses
- patch proposed that could be integrated in upcoming 1.5 pkg release
- (as of 2015-04-25) I can confirm that patch has been integrated in 1.5 release, and that this release is currently used on FreeBSD 10.1 : problem solved.

---

Not really a true answer but it could help anyone facing same problem. Here is the Python code for a minimal proxy collating the whole file received in chunked mode and giving it back with a Content-Length header :

```
# -*- coding: latin1 -*-

import urllib.request
import http.server
import logging

class Handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    HEADERS = [ 'If-Modified-Since', 'Host', 'User-Agent', 'Accept',
                'Connection' ]
    def do_GET(self):
        logging.debug("Got a request %s", self.path)
        if self.server.debug >= 3:
            logging.debug("Original headers %s", self.headers.as_string())
        req = urllib.request.Request(self.path)
        for (key, value) in self.headers.items():
            if key in __class__.HEADERS:
                req.add_header(key, value)
        if self.server.debug >= 4:
            logging.debug("Send headers %s", str(req.headers))                
        r = self.server.opener.open(req)
        code = r.getcode()
        logging.debug('Code %d', code)
        if self.server.debug >= 3:
            logging.debug("Received headers %s", str(r.headers))
        if code == 200 and self.server.chunk:
            self.send_response(code)
            self.send_header('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
            self.end_headers()
            while True:
                t = r.read(4095)
                logging.debug('Chunk : %d', len(t))
                self.wfile.write(("%03x\r\n" % (len(t),)).encode())
                if len(t) == 0:
                    self.wfile.write(b"\r\n")
                    break
                else:
                    self.wfile.write(t)
                    self.wfile.write(b"\r\n")
        else:
            t = r.readall()
            #print(t)
            self.send_response(code)
            logging.debug('Content-Length %d', len(t))
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(t))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(t)

class MiniProxy(http.server.HTTPServer):
    def __init__(self, port=8080, relay=None, chunk=False, debug=0):
        http.server.HTTPServer.__init__(self, ('', port), Handler)
        self.port = port
        self.relay = relay
        self.chunk = chunk
        self.debug= debug
        if relay is not None:
            logging.info("relay set to", relay)
            self.proxyHandler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(
                {'http': relay})
            self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener(self.proxyHandler)
        else:
            self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description =
                      "Simple HTTP proxy to chunk or unchunk responses")
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--chunk', dest = 'chunk', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-C', '--no-chunk', dest = 'chunk', action='store_false')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--relay')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int,  default = 8080)
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', type=int, default = 0)
    params = parser.parse_args()
    proxy = MiniProxy(port = params.port, relay = params.relay,
                      chunk = params.chunk, debug = params.debug)

    logging_format = '%(levelname)s:%(message)s'
    if params.debug == 1:
        logging.basicConfig(format=logging_format, level=logging.INFO)
    elif params.debug >= 2:
        logging.basicConfig(format=logging_format, level=logging.DEBUG)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(format=logging_format)        
    try:
        print (sys.argv[0], "listen on", proxy.port)
        proxy.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stop')
        #proxy.shutdown()
```